# How to get details of log form dashboards of kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Hi I am new to Kibana (ELK stack).I have created an error dashboard in Kibana but If I need more information about errors how can I get that.Like If I want to know because of what error has been created.How can I get it.

Any initiatives will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For any information that you want to display in Kibana you need to have a source from where that particular information is available. In this case if we assume that the logs being parsed by Logstash has the information on the errors, then you can parse/filter the logs via the pipeline of Logstash to extract the information and store it in a field.

Now the document which are saved in the ES contain the information, this can be used to perform various aggregations or apply different mathematical functions and then eventually visualize it.

Comment: Yes,I am able to visualize the error in the form of graph but if I need to find it from graph where the error has occurred how can I find it from graph.